# PHPDoc for conditional polymorphic call

Tags: php, laravel, type-hinting, phpdoc, php-8

For `$item` there's a polymorphic `loggable` relationship. In the database this is stored in `items` as `loggable_type` and `loggable_id` (for PHP 8+ in and Laravel).

```php
for($items as $item) {
    // ...

    if ($item->loggable_type === Comment::class) {
        $item->loggable->resetDates();
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to type hint that `loggable` within the condition is a `Comment`. I think I might be able to user `@var` but doing something like `/* @var $item->loggable Comment */` doesn't work and I can't do `/* @var $item Comment */` since that sets it to `$item` and not its property.

I'm thinking of changing the condition to `if ($item->loggable instance of Comment)`, however I'd rather not since that requires loading and creating the Comment even if it's not used.

Is there a way to type hint `$item->loggable` as `Comment`?

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to variable

```php
for($items as $item) {
    if ($item->loggable_type === Comment::class) {
        /** @var Comment $loggable */
        $loggable = $item->loggable;
        
        $loggable->resetDates();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Justinas stated, either assign it to a variable:

```php
for ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->loggable_type === Comment::class) {
        /** @var Comment $loggable */
        $loggable = $item->loggable;
        
        $loggable->resetDates();
    }
}
```

Or set the possible values you could have (if they are fixed and known) on the model itself like this:

```php
/**
 * @property Comment|WhateverModel|Model $loggable
 */
class Item extends Model
{
   // ...
}
```

That will tell the IDE that the property `loggable` is possibly a `Comment` object, `WhateverModel` object, or `Model` object (so you still have normal Model's methods auto-completion).

If you can narrow down which classes you could have there, then add them, else I would go with the first option (assign a value and use a PHPDoc block for a variable)

Comment: Interesting second approach. Having a kind of ide helper/stub to type hint.